# segfault with in genops while pthread_create after libcurl/RTSP

Tags: c, curl, segmentation-fault, pthreads, libcurl

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

#define SW_URL_STR_lEN 255
struct test_url {
    char protocol[SW_URL_STR_lEN];
    char hostname[SW_URL_STR_lEN];
    char page[SW_URL_STR_lEN];
    int port;
};

typedef struct test_url test_url_t;
test_url_t *test_create_url();
void test_destroy_url(test_url_t *url);
bool test_parse_url(test_url_t *url, const char *to_parse);



static int _getch(void) {
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int ch;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);

    return ch;
}

static size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    (void) ptr;

    if (size * nmemb > BUFFER_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error buffer too small");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *buf = (char *) userdata;

    strncpy(buf, ptr, size * nmemb);

    return size * nmemb;
}

static void send_rtsp_options_request(CURL *handle, const char *uri) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nRTSP: OPTIONS %s\n", uri);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, uri);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_OPTIONS);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
}

static void send_rtsp_describe_request(CURL *handle, const char *uri, char *str_sdp) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nRTSP: DESCRIBE %s\n", uri);

    fprintf(stdout, " describe: %s", str_sdp);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, str_sdp);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_DESCRIBE);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
}

static void send_rtsp_setup_request(CURL *handle, const char *uri, const char *transport) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nRTSP: SETUP %s\n", uri);
    fprintf(stdout, "      TRANSPORT %s\n", transport);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, uri);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_TRANSPORT, transport);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_SETUP);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
}

static void send_rtsp_play_request(CURL *handle, const char *uri, const char *range) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nRTSP: PLAY %s\n", uri);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, uri);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RANGE, range);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_PLAY);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);

    /* Disable ranges */
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RANGE, NULL);
}

// static void send_rtsp_pause_request(CURL *handken, const char *uri, const char *range) {
//  fprintf(stdout, "\nRTSP: PAUSE %s\n", uri);
//  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, uri);
//     curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RANGE, range);
//     curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_PAUSE);
//     curl_easy_perform(handle);

//     /* Disable ranges */
//     curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RANGE, NULL);
// }

static void send_rtsp_teardown_request(CURL *handle, const char *uri) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nRTSP: TEARDOWN %s\n", uri);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_TEARDOWN);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
}

/* Main options */
typedef enum {
    rtsp_injector_arg_help       =     'h',
    rtsp_injector_arg_addr       =     'a',
    rtsp_injector_arg_verbose    =     'v',
} rtsp_injector_arg_t;

static void rtsp_print_help() {
    fprintf(stdout, "Usage: \n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\t-%c, --help\n", rtsp_injector_arg_help);
    fprintf(stdout, "\t\tprints this help, and exits\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\t-%c, --rtsp-addr\n", rtsp_injector_arg_addr);
    fprintf(stdout, "\t\tThe rtsp address of the server, with the port and the right camera choice such as \
                            \n\t\tActive camera - 'rtsp://(device ip address):5554/camera' \
                            \n\t\tBack camera - 'rtsp://(device ip address):5554/back' \
                            \n\t\tFront camera - 'rtsp://(device ip address):5554/front'\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\t-%c, --verbose\n", rtsp_injector_arg_verbose);
    fprintf(stdout, "\t\tprints more details in the packets trading\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

static void *pthread_proc(void *arg) {
    (void)arg;
    fprintf(stdout, "COIN COIN\n");
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        rtsp_print_help();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"help",        no_argument,        NULL,    rtsp_injector_arg_help       },
        {"rtsp-addr",   required_argument,  NULL,    rtsp_injector_arg_addr       },
        {"verbose",     no_argument,        NULL,    rtsp_injector_arg_verbose    },
        { NULL,         0,                  NULL,    0                            },
    };

    int option_index = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char opstring[1024] = {0};
    size_t s = 0;
    pthread_t thrd;
//    pthread_create(&thrd, NULL, pthread_proc, NULL);
    s += snprintf(opstring + s, sizeof(opstring) - s, "%c", rtsp_injector_arg_help);
    s += snprintf(opstring + s, sizeof(opstring) - s, "%c:", rtsp_injector_arg_addr);
    s += snprintf(opstring + s, sizeof(opstring) - s, "%c", rtsp_injector_arg_verbose);

    long verbose_is_on = 0L;
    char *url = NULL;

    while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, opstring, long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case rtsp_injector_arg_help:
                rtsp_print_help();
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            case rtsp_injector_arg_addr:
                url = optarg;
                break;
            case rtsp_injector_arg_verbose:
                verbose_is_on = 1L;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stdout, "Invalid option 0%o: '%c' ??\n", c, c);
                rtsp_print_help();
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (url == NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Missing mandatory prefix '-a' to the server address\n");
        rtsp_print_help();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int res = 0;

    /* Where the PLAY starts and when should it ends */
    const char *range = "0.000-";
    char uri[1024] = {0};
//     char control[1024] = {0};
    char str_sdp[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    /* Initialize all libcurl sub moduless */
    res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stdout, "curl_global_init failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Create a sesion handle */
    CURL *my_handle = curl_easy_init();
    if (my_handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "curl_easy_init failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Set the url to work with, must to be the right format ie RFC , the function doesn't check it */
    curl_easy_setopt(my_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    /* Parse server information ie ip and port */
    test_url_t *my_url = test_create_url();
    test_parse_url(my_url, url);

    fprintf(stdout, "Protocol: %s\nHostname: %s\nPort: %d\nPage: %s\n",
            my_url->protocol, my_url->hostname, my_url->port, my_url->page);

    curl_easy_setopt(my_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(my_handle, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, stdout);

    curl_easy_setopt(my_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "test-client-rtsp");

    curl_easy_setopt(my_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, verbose_is_on);

    /* Let's send some requests */
    snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), "%s", url);

    /* OPTIONS */
    send_rtsp_options_request(my_handle, uri);

    /* DESCRIBE */
    send_rtsp_describe_request(my_handle, uri, str_sdp);
    fprintf(stdout, "Sdp information:\n%s", str_sdp);


    // char *transport = "RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;client_port=1234-1235";
    char transport[1024] = "RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=1234-1235";
    fprintf(stdout, "Transport: %s", transport);

    /* SETUP */
    snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), "%s", url);
    strncat(uri, "/trackID=0", strlen(uri)); /* Different url for SETUP, check doc in trac with the scenari exemple */
    send_rtsp_setup_request(my_handle, uri, transport);

    /* PLAY */
    snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), "%s", url);
    send_rtsp_play_request(my_handle, uri, range);
    pthread_create(&thrd, NULL, pthread_proc, NULL);
    _getch();

    /* TEARDOWN */
    send_rtsp_teardown_request(my_handle, uri);

    /* Destroy the session handle */
    curl_easy_cleanup(my_handle);

    /* Cleanup curl init resources */
    curl_global_cleanup();
    test_destroy_url(my_url);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}




test_url_t * test_create_url() {
    test_url_t *ret = NULL;

    ret = malloc(sizeof(test_url_t));
    if (!ret) {
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(ret, 0, sizeof(test_url_t));

    return ret;
}

void test_destroy_url(test_url_t *url) {
    free(url);
}

bool test_parse_url(test_url_t *url, const char *to_parse) {
    int pos_of_hostname = 0, pos_port = 0, pos_page = 0;
    const char *hostname = NULL;
    const char *str_port = NULL;
    const char *str_page = NULL;
    char str_port_number[4];

    if (to_parse == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    hostname = strstr(to_parse, "://");
    if (hostname == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    pos_of_hostname = hostname - to_parse; /* Get the position of "://" */
    if (pos_of_hostname > (int)sizeof(url->protocol)) {
        return false;
    }
    strncpy(url->protocol, to_parse, sizeof(url->protocol));
    url->protocol[pos_of_hostname] = '\0';

    hostname = to_parse + pos_of_hostname + 3; /* Skip protocol and '://' */

    /* Check if port is provided */
    str_port = strstr(hostname, ":");
    if (str_port != NULL) {
        pos_port = str_port - hostname;
        strncpy(url->hostname, hostname, sizeof(url->hostname));
        url->hostname[pos_port] = '\0';
        str_page = strstr(hostname, "/");
        if (str_page != NULL) { /* Check if page is provided */
            pos_page = str_page - hostname;
            str_page = hostname + pos_page + 1;
            strncpy(url->page, str_page, sizeof(url->page));
            if (pos_port < pos_page) { /* Check if ':' is before '/' ex: ':8080/something' */
                strncpy(url->hostname, hostname, sizeof(url->hostname));
                url->hostname[pos_port] = '\0';
                /* Port number is provided */
                str_page = hostname + pos_port + 1; /* Skip hostname and the ':' before port number' */
                strncpy(str_port_number, str_page, sizeof(str_port_number));
                url->port = atoi(str_port_number);
            }
            else { /* Page provided before port */
                /* Warning: strncpy doesn't put a '\0' at the end of the string if src doesn't have one*/
                strncpy(url->hostname, hostname, sizeof(url->hostname));
                url->hostname[pos_page] = '\0';
            }
        }
        else { /* There is no page provided */
            str_page = hostname + pos_port + 1;
                strncpy(str_port_number, str_page, sizeof(str_port_number));
                url->port = atoi(str_port_number);
        }
    }
    else { /* Only page provided */
        str_page = strstr(hostname, "/");
        if (str_page != NULL) { /* Check if page is provided */
            pos_page = str_page - hostname;
            str_page = hostname + pos_page + 1;
            strncpy(url->page, str_page, sizeof(url->page));
            url->page[strlen(str_page)] = '\0';
            strncpy(url->hostname, hostname, sizeof(url->hostname));
            url->hostname[pos_page] = '\0';
        }
        else { /* Case where there is only a hostname provided */
            strncpy(url->hostname, hostname, sizeof(url->hostname));
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The code crashes on pthread_create line 256 with the following backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI__IO_enable_locks () at genops.c:552
552     genops.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI__IO_enable_locks () at genops.c:552
#1  0x00007ffff7bbe52d in __pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=<optimized out>, attr=0x0, start_routine=<optimized out>, arg=0x0) at pthread_create.c:736
#2  0x0000555555557db5 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffd988) at test_client_rtsp.c:256
```

If I uncomment the first pthread_create, and comment the second one, it works fine. I take it this has to do with libcurl, but I'm not too sure it.

Curl 7.64.0 is compiled with:

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ldap --disable-sspi --without-librtmp --disable-ftp --disable-file --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-smb --without-libidn --without-zlib --without-ssl --enable-rtsp
```

I'm kinda lost as to what is going on there.

Comment: First, why do you set options after executing the request ? Second, you need to cleanup the curl handle after every execution or create a new one (with curl_easy_cleanup).

Comment: I don't get you're saying. From the doc:
You can do any amount of calls to curl_easy_perform while using the same easy_handle
So clearly, I should be able to use the same handle from curl_easy_init throughout the code.

Comment: yes you can call curl_easy_perfom with the same handle, but not add options after the first perform. You can only change the state of the handle before the perfom. You can do this by putting common initialization parts in a function and add specific options after and then do the perfom. Cleanup whenever you want to reuse the handle. That's the common way to use curl.